# Selenium Webdriver - Store multiple linktext's

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a web application using Selenium Webdriver(Java), but having difficulty in storing multiple linktext's. Below is my html code, I have to fetch all email id's to verify before inserting new one.

```
<tr class="odd" >
      <td><input type="radio" name="item" value="52"></td>
      <td><a href="/Abcdef/UpdateAction.do?userno=52">abcd.xyz@abc.com</a></td>
      <td>Abcd Xyz</td>
      <td>internal</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" >
      <td><input type="radio" name="item" value="151"></td>
      <td><a href="/Abcdef/UpdateAction.do?userno=151">klmn.opqr@abc.com</a></td>
      <td>Klmn Opqr</td>
      <td>internal</td>
```

.
      .

Likewise it has around 20 linktext's(email id's) and those email id's need to be stored for verification.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would try to find the table and store it inside `WebElement` variable. Lets call the variable `table`
2. Then, inside the table try to call `List<WebElement> emails = table.findElements(By.partialLinkText("0"));`
3. All emails should be stored here, in form of `WebElement` classes
4. to get the mail in readable form you can call `getText` on each of item from the list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your earlier reply.

I used below code to print all linktext's with in table.

```
 WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("table_id"));
 List<WebElement> emails = table.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
 for(WebElement tdElement : emails) { 
 System.out.println(tdElement.getText()); 
 }
```